# C# How to make this code easier and shorter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am beginner and i wanna ask how to make this code more simple and shorter
Thanks for all replies

```
public static bool SelectedSingleAcc(SpecialForms.AccountManager am)
{
    //checkbox1
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == true 
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox2
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == true  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox3
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == true  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox4
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == true  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox5
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == true  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox6
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == true  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox7
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == true  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == false) return true;
    //checkbox8
    if (am.selectedCB1.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB2.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB3.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB4.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB5.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB6.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB7.Checked == false  
        && am.selectedCB8.Checked == true) return true;
            
    return false;
}
```

Comment: analyse your logic ans write _nested_ ifs. or store your input/output combination in a dictionary and look up the result.

Comment: Use a set of radio buttons

Comment: It would help if you *described* what the logic is meant to achieve rather than rely on us reverse engineering the intent from code you already know is difficult to read.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: I agree with @CaiusJard - checkboxes are for multi select, for a single selectable item, use radio buttons instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// get all values into an array for easier handling:
values = new[] 
{
    am.selectedCB1.Checked,
    am.selectedCB2.Checked,
    am.selectedCB3.Checked,
    am.selectedCB4.Checked,
    am.selectedCB5.Checked,
    am.selectedCB6.Checked,
    am.selectedCB7.Checked,
    am.selectedCB8.Checked,
};

// find out if exactly one is true
return values.Count(val => val == true) == 1;
```

---

That said... the correct UI decision would be to use radio buttons instead of check boxes. They already implement this logic for you. And any time you catch yourself *numbering* your variables, you should think hard about why this should *not* be an array instead of many single variables.

Comment: or `Count(val => val)`

Comment: @YongShun `.Any(val => val)` is not the same as `.Count(val => val) == 1` and `.Any(val)` won't compile unless you've defined `val` elsewhere to be the name of some delegate that accepts a boolean and returns a boolean

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool SelectedSingleAcc(SpecialForms.AccountManager am)
        {
            int checkedNumbers = 0;
            if (am.selectedCB1.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB2.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB3.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB4.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB5.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB6.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB7.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            if (am.selectedCB9.Checked) checkedNumbers++;
            
            if (checkedNumbers == 1) //only one checkbox selected, we think the result is true
                 return true;
            
            return false;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you're checking that at most one checkbox is checked the n return true, otherwise return false

Because, in order to even appear on a form, controls have to be added to a Controls collection we can search through it (using LINQ) looking for controls that match a criteria. In this case we'll look through the controls for any that are checkboxes, and counting those whose name starts with "selectedCB" and whose state is checked. We compare the count to 1, and if there is only 1 then the result is true, if there are 0 or 2+ the result is false:

```
return p.Controls
  .OfType<Checkbox>()
  .Count(c => c.Name.StartsWith("selectedCB") && c.Checked) == 1;
```

- `p` is the name of the panel/group box  that holds the checkboxes.
- If they are straight on the form use `this` (or the name of the form variable, if this code isn't part of the form that holds the boxes).
- If there are no other checkboxes in the panel/on the form you can remove the `c.Name.StartsWith...`. The check on name is purely there to stop e.g. your isActiveCheckbox being checked and hence also polluting the count
- If there are other checkboxes also having a name that starts with "selectedCB", it would be simplest to rename them so that only these 8 checkboxes have a name starting with "selectedCB", or put them in their own panel but add a comment if you want a more refined logic eg a Regex that insists the name be `selectedCB[1-8]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rule you're implementing is an exclusive OR condition between then status of the 8 checkboxes.

IN that case using C#'s XOR operator `^` would probably yield a contender for the shortest solution e.g.

```
public static bool SelectedSingleAcc(SpecialForms.AccountManager am)
{
    return am.selectedCB1.Checked   
           ^ am.selectedCB2.Checked
           ^ am.selectedCB3.Checked
           ^ am.selectedCB4.Checked
           ^ am.selectedCB5.Checked  
           ^ am.selectedCB6.Checked
           ^ am.selectedCB7.Checked
           ^ am.selectedCB8.Checked;
}
```

With that said, I would advise against using the XOR `^` operator, and consider something similar to nvoigt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967035/17536565), on the grounds that it is seldom used meaning many developers wouldn't be familiar with it, thereby impeding the code's readability.